# Keras LSTM to predict next word with variable length sequences

Tags: keras, deep-learning, sequence, lstm

I have a set of sequences of variable length and I want to build a model that predicts the next token given the past many tokens.

The question is, how can I train a model with variable length sequences?

I'm aware of padding but, is there a way to not pre-specify the window length?

I also read about using a `batch_size = 1`. In this case, what should the train_X and train_Y be? If I use as target only the last token of a very long sequence, it's like I'm discarding all the subsequences in it (i.e. from 0->1, 0->2.... 0->N-1). Should I manually create all these subsequences before feeding the LSTM?

Comment: I think I have same problem as you. I have list of sequences with different sizes. Model should predict next items based on previous items. I don't know how should I pass targets when using `fit`. Have you solved this?

Comment: @MarcinLagowski I ended up writing a generator which yields fixed size subsequences where the target is the next element. You can train the model with `fit_generator()`. Although this works, it discards the internal LSTM cell state between each batch.

Comment: So you are generating sequences like `(..., (seq[0:5], seq[6]), (seq[1:6], seq[7]),...)`? Did you tried to generator something like `(..., (seq[0:5], seq[6]), (seq[0:6], seq[7]),...)`?

Comment: Yes I did the 1st approach you are showing. No, I didn't try the latter one. Please let me know if you try and get some results.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can specify variable length inputs in Keras, namely by specifying `input_shape=(None, features)` where `None` indicates *unknown* number of timesteps. Here is an example model:

```python
in = Input(shape=(None, num_words)) # let's assume it is one-hot encoded words
latent = Masking()(in) # sentences in same batch need to same length, padded
latent = LSTM(latent_size)(latent) # skips masked timesteps
out = Dense(num_words, activation='softmax')
model = Model(in, out)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

The crucial point is that the sentences in batch need to be padded for tensor operations but in effect different batches can have different number of timesteps allowing your model to process varying length sentences.

Comment: OK. So within each batch, how should I pre-process the sequences in order to be able to use them for training? (related to my questions in the last paragraph of my post above).

Comment: If you just have a single sequence and haven't chopped anything up, use [TimeseriesGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#timeseriesgenerator) that will create a sliding window style data over your sequence.

Comment: I have multiple sequences, not just one. So, within each batch do I still need to pre-process the data? If so, how? How will the LSTM learn the dependency on the whole sequence and only on some windows?

Comment: Then you have 2 options, either pad every sentence using `pad_sequences` and use `model.fit` or write a custom [Sequence](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) that generates batches and only pad within batch using `model.fit_generator`.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't quite get it. What should each sequence include? Should I break my long sequence into subsequences? If I do so, don't I miss learning the whole sequence structure?

Comment: Suppose you have `seqs` a list of sentences. In a generator, assuming your batch size is 10, you take `seqs[:10]` then you encode words, then you pad_sequences giving you (10, batch_max_length, num_words) if one-hot encoded.

Comment: OK. During `fit()` the target will be the last word of each sequence I guess, right? My question is, how will the model learn to predict the next word if, for each sequence, I give just one example?

Answer (score -1):

In keras, you need fihed input shapes, but you can pad the sequences (fill with 0 for example) to have the same sizes.

A LSTM take a 3d input : (batch_size , timesteps, features). Timesteps represents the words, and features the representation of a single word. Let's say you have sentences of 20 words, and each word of the sentence is represented as a OneHot vector of 1000 elements. for a single sentence, your input shape have to be (1 , 20 , 1000). You can manually preprocess your data to fit these conditions, or you can use pre built functions in keras that will do the work for you. You can find all these functions here : https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/

Comment: You don't need fixed input shapes, Keras supports variable input lengths.

Comment: This is not true. If you want Keras to ignore some elements, you can use Maksing or not specify the number of timesteps, but It does not work with all the layers of Keras.